# Keras retrieve value of node before activation function

Tags: python, neural-network, keras, logistic-regression

Imagine a fully-connected neural network with its last two layers of the following structure:

```
[Dense]
    units = 612
    activation = softplus

[Dense]
    units = 1
    activation = sigmoid
```

The output value of the net is 1, but I'd like to know what the input x to the sigmoidal function was (must be some high number, since sigm(x) is 1 here).

Folllowing [indraforyou's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41712013/1922302) answer I managed to retrieve the output and weights of Keras layers:

```
outputs = [layer.output for layer in model.layers[-2:]]
functors = [K.function( [model.input]+[K.learning_phase()], [out] ) for out in outputs]

test_input = np.array(...)
layer_outs = [func([test_input, 0.]) for func in functors]

print layer_outs[-1][0]  # -> array([[ 1.]])

dense_0_out = layer_outs[-2][0]                           # shape (612, 1)
dense_1_weights = model.layers[-1].weights[0].get_value() # shape (1, 612)
dense_1_bias = model.layers[-1].weights[1].get_value()

x = np.dot(dense_0_out, dense_1_weights) + dense_1_bias
print x # -> -11.7
```

How can x be a negative number? In that case the last layers output should be a number closer to 0.0 than 1.0. Are `dense_0_out` or `dense_1_weights` the wrong outputs or weights?